# C++ Remove Objects in List at Loop

Tags: c++, stl

How can i delete **all** objects which are works finished

I using the following code but get *list iterator not incrementable*

How can I remove it without deleting it

```
list<A*> myList;
for(list<A*>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it !=myList.end(); ++it ){
    (*it )->DoSomething();
    if((*it )->WorksFnished()){
        //myList.erase(it );    <- It's works but I get exception after the loop
        //myList.remove(*it );  <- It's works but I get exception after the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`erase` returns an iterator

```
list<A*> myList;
list<A*>::iterator it = myList.begin();
while( it != myList.end() ) {
    (*it)->DoSomething();
    if( (*it)->WorksFnished() ) {
        it = myList.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the fact that `erase` returns a new iterator, as described in other answers here. For performance-critical code, that might be the best solution. But personally, I would favor splitting the loop into separate processing and removal steps for readability and clarity:

```
// Assumes C++ 11 compatible compiler
list<A*> myList;
// Processing
for(const auto* each : myList){
    each->DoSomething();
}

// Deletion
myList.remove_if([](A* each) {
    return each->WorksFnished();
});
```

If you don't want to use `remove_if`, some alternatives are:

- Copy all objects you want to **keep** into a new list, then `std::swap` it with your current list
- Use a temporary list `toBeRemoved`, and add all objects that should be removed to that. When you're finished iterating over the actual list, iterate `toBeRemoved` and call `myList.erase` for each element

Comment: You use the handy C++11 lambda but miss a chance for the range-based for loop.  You could also move `(*it)->DoSomething()` into the lambda inside the remove_if.

Comment: @GuyGreer I could, but that's mixing different concerns, and rather hacky for my taste. I personally wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: @sp2danny that's not true for the `list`-specific version, only for the generic `<algorithm>`-one.

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround..

increment the number of objects from the list that has `WorkFnished`.
then after the loop. if the accumulator match the list size, clear it.

```
size_t nFinished = 0;
list<A*> myList;
for(list<A*>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it !=myList.end(); ++it ){
    (*it )->DoSomething();
    if((*it )->WorksFnished()){
         nFinished++;
    }
}

if (nFinished == myList.size())
{
     myList.clear();
}
```

Comment: This will keep everything or nothing, which doesn't seem to be the same as what the OP wants.

Comment: @GuyGreer: `How can i delete all objects which are works finished` - sounds like this is what he wanted... clear `ALL` objects... but anyhow, there is an answer that worked for him

Comment: Thank you bro but no i want **which are works finished**

Answer (score 1):

If you use `erase` you have to assign it back to the iterator. In this case, we have to take care of the incrementing ourselves depending if the current element was erased or not.

```
list<A*> myList;
for (auto it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); )
{
    (*it)->DoSomething();
    if( (*it)->WorksFnished() ) {
        it = myList.erase(it);    // Sets it to the next element
    } else {
        ++it;        // Increments it since no erasing
    }
}
```

[std::list::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/)

> Return: An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call. This is the container end if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.